# Touch Move Method issue in cocos2d for iphon4

Tags: objective-c, ios5, cocos2d-iphone

I am developing one universal puzzle game, in which i have used separate image for iphone4 and for iphone3, iphone4 image is double in size of iphone3 image. My issue is for iphone4, touch area of image for iphone4 image is taking double size, suppose i have an image size for iphone4 is 20*40 and for iphone3 is 10*20, issue is touch area for iphone4 image is 40*80 i don't know how its happening i worked out in my code but i didnt get any solution of this issue, touching is working fine in iphone3, taking with in sprite rectangle.

can you one help me to solve this issue or tell me what i am forgetting to code for iphone4 touching so that its take touch with in sprite (image) rectangle

Thank in advance.
 Here is my code:

```
  `-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
     {


    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    touchLocation = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
   touchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:touchLocation];
    touchLocation = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];
    NSLog(@"touch location x = %f , y =%f",touchLocation.x,touchLocation.y);
   CCSprite * sp= [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"1.png"];
   sp.position = ccp(touchLocation.x ,touchLocation.y);
   // [self addChild:sp z:100];
   CGRect myrec = [invisible[0] boundingBox];
   if (CGRectContainsPoint(myrec, touchLocation) ) {
    NSLog(@"oneeeeeeee");


   }


   [self selectSpriteForTouch:touchLocation];      
   // return TRUE; 


   }


   - (void)panForTranslation:(CGPoint)translation {    
    if (selSprite) {


    CGPoint newPos = ccpAdd(selSprite.position, translation);
    selSprite.position = newPos;

  } 


     }


  - (void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {   
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    Location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    Location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:Location];
    Location = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];
    NSLog(@"touch moved location x = %f , y =%f",Location.x,Location.y);

  //touchLocation = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];

   CGPoint oldTouchLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:touch.view];
    oldTouchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:oldTouchLocation];
    oldTouchLocation = [self convertToNodeSpace:oldTouchLocation];
    CGPoint translation = ccpSub(Location, oldTouchLocation); 

   if (CGRectContainsPoint(selspriterect,Location)) 

   {
    [self panForTranslation:translation];
    }


   if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) 
 {
    NSLog(@"respond to selector");

    CGFloat scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];

    if (scale > 1.0) 
    {
        NSLog(@"iphone 4s");
        CGPoint mypoint = CGPointMake(80, 357);
        CGPoint mypoint1 = CGPointMake(237, 360);
        CGPoint mypoint2 = CGPointMake(79, 255);
        CGPoint mypoint3 = CGPointMake(237, 247);
        CGPoint mypoint4 = CGPointMake(78, 153);
        CGPoint mypoint5 = CGPointMake(239, 140);


        CCSprite *disablesprite=nil;
        switch (selSprite.tag) {
            case 0:
                if (CGRectContainsPoint( [dest[0] boundingBox] , mypoint ) ) {
                    NSLog(@"oneeeeee collided");
                    dest[0].position =  ccp(192,380);
                    // selSprite = disablesprite;
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                if (CGRectContainsPoint( [dest[1] boundingBox] , mypoint1 ) ) {
                    NSLog(@"two collided");
                    dest[1].position =  ccp(258,379);

                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if (CGRectContainsPoint( [dest[2] boundingBox] , mypoint2 ) ) {
                    NSLog(@"three collided");
                    dest[2].position =  ccp(173,281);
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                if (CGRectContainsPoint( [dest[3] boundingBox] , mypoint3 ) ) {
                    NSLog(@"four collided");
                    dest[3].position = ccp(258,281);

                }
                break;
            case 4:
                if (CGRectContainsPoint( [dest[4] boundingBox] , mypoint4 ) ) {
                    NSLog(@"five collided");
                    dest[4].position =   ccp(166,181);
                }
                break;
            case 5:
                if (CGRectContainsPoint( [dest[5] boundingBox] , mypoint5 ) ) {
                    NSLog(@"six collided");
                    dest[5].position =  ccp(258,176);

                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }
    else {

   CGPoint mypoint = CGPointMake(106, 329);
   CGPoint mypoint1 = CGPointMake(208, 329);
   CGPoint mypoint2 = CGPointMake(97, 220);
   CGPoint mypoint3 = CGPointMake(217, 220);
   CGPoint mypoint4 = CGPointMake(92, 124);
   CGPoint mypoint5 = CGPointMake(212, 124);




  CCSprite *disablesprite=nil;
  switch (selSprite.tag) {
    case 0:
        if (CGRectContainsPoint( [dest[0] boundingBox] , mypoint ) ) {
            NSLog(@"oneeeeee collided");
            dest[0].position =  ccp(125,320);
            // selSprite = disablesprite;
        }
        break;
    case 1:
        if (CGRectContainsPoint( [dest[1] boundingBox] , mypoint1 ) ) {
            NSLog(@"two collided");
            dest[1].position =  ccp(200,312);

        }
        break;
    case 2:
        if (CGRectContainsPoint( [dest[2] boundingBox] , mypoint2 ) ) {
            NSLog(@"three collided");
            dest[2].position =  ccp(117,209);
        }
        break;
    case 3:
        if (CGRectContainsPoint( [dest[3] boundingBox] , mypoint3 ) ) {
            NSLog(@"four collided");
            dest[3].position =  ccp(200,208);

        }
        break;
    case 4:
        if (CGRectContainsPoint( [dest[4] boundingBox] , mypoint4 ) ) {
            NSLog(@"five collided");
            dest[4].position =  ccp(113,127);
        }
        break;
    case 5:
        if (CGRectContainsPoint( [dest[5] boundingBox] , mypoint5 ) ) {
            NSLog(@"six collided");
            dest[5].position =  ccp(207,126);

        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
  }
    }
  }

  }   
  -(void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
  CGPoint mypoint = CGPointMake(106, 329);
  CGPoint mypoint1 = CGPointMake(208, 329);
  CGPoint mypoint2 = CGPointMake(97, 220);
  CGPoint mypoint3 = CGPointMake(217, 220);
  CGPoint mypoint4 = CGPointMake(92, 124);
  CGPoint mypoint5 = CGPointMake(212, 124);
  switch (selSprite.tag) {
    case 0:
        if (CGRectContainsPoint( [dest[0] boundingBox] , mypoint ) ) {
            NSLog(@"oneeeeee collided");
            if (corsprite == TRUE) {
                correctplace++;
                corsprite = FALSE;
            }
        }else {
            selSprite.position = ccp(110,50);
        }
        break;
    case 1:
        if (CGRectContainsPoint( [dest[1] boundingBox] , mypoint1 ) ) {
            NSLog(@"two collided");
            if (corsprite2 == TRUE) {
                correctplace++;
                corsprite2 = FALSE;
            }
        }else {
            selSprite.position = ccp(110, 65);
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        if (CGRectContainsPoint( [dest[2] boundingBox] , mypoint2 ) ) {
            NSLog(@"three collided");
            if (corsprite3 == TRUE) {
                correctplace++;
                corsprite3 = FALSE;
            }
        }else {
            selSprite.position =ccp(130, 10);
        }
        break;
    case 3:
        if (CGRectContainsPoint( [dest[3] boundingBox] , mypoint3 ) ) {
            NSLog(@"four collided");
            if (corsprite4 == TRUE) {
                correctplace++;
                corsprite4 = FALSE;
            }
        }else {
            selSprite.position = ccp(215, 10);
        }
        break;
    case 4:
        if (CGRectContainsPoint( [dest[4] boundingBox] , mypoint4 ) ) {
            NSLog(@"five collided");
            if (corsprite5 == TRUE) {
                correctplace++;
                corsprite5 = FALSE;
            }
        }else {
            selSprite.position = ccp(220,70);
        }
        break;
    case 5:
        if (CGRectContainsPoint( [dest[5] boundingBox] , mypoint5 ) ) {
            NSLog(@"six collided");
            if (corsprite6 == TRUE) {
                correctplace++;
                corsprite6 = FALSE;
            }           
        }else {
            selSprite.position = ccp(220,70);
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
  }
```

`

Comment: post some code : ccTouchBegan, the code you use to detect iPhone model, etc ... and any logic you may have according to the phone model (if any). Also, verify on iPhone itself, in ccTouchBegan, log the contentScaleFactor.

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your app delegate

```
[director enableRetinaDisplay:YES];
```

and make sure your images follows the convention.

e.g. for iPhone3 suppose you have image as `image.png` 
then your retina image must be `image-hd.png`

Comment: I had enable Retina display and i have used naming convention also like you has mention, images working fine, only problem in touching.

Answer (score 0):

Well, everything should be in points e.g. i dont think you need the logic around the UIScreen scale property, and your logic for scale=1 should work identically on a retina and non-retina display.

Quick try : change scale > 1.0 to scale > 3.0 (the if should always branch to the else part, which you state 'works' on iPhone 3), just to see if this is correct. If it is, remove the logic around scale altogether and cleanup :) ... In my code, i have not had one legitimate case of figuring out whether the scale is 1.0 or otherwise.

Comment: I changed scale >1.0 to scale >3.0, but i am having still same issue.

Comment: Actually my game is universal and here i am using masking for breaking image in irregular shape,this is my question which i asked in this forum;  [link ( http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/27650/how-do-i-break-an-image-into-6-or-8-pieces-of-different-shapes)] , for masking i am using this tutorial  [link(http://www.raywenderlich.com/4421/how-to-mask-a-sprite-with-cocos2d-1-0)].

Comment: using masking i am breaking image in runtime and then i am showing mask image as a original image(Dest[i]) and then makeing them to fall down, after that i am using touch method to move that image and placed at there original positio, its working fine in iphone3 but in iphone4 touching area is double of image rectangle. waiting for your reply . thanks !